# vscode reformatting react js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have VS Code and use it to edit my ReactJS application, along with several other people. I have the React Snippets extension installed but nothing else. It seems VS Code is reformatting my code, however, so that whenever I commit something with a small change, there are 20,000 diffs to review because of whitespace changes. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: Go into preferences and turn off format on save. Or select null/none as your default formatter.

Comment: It should also be noted that if there is a prettier config file in the root directory, than you should just download the prettier extension so that your code will be formatted the same way as the rest of the project.